# "No such file or directory" messages when using GDB with C++ programs

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm pretty new to using GDB, so sorry if this is a noob question.

When using GDB on any C++ program, I get a large number of "No such file or directory" messages. This does not happen with C programs.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
$ g++ -g hello-world.cpp -o hello-world.o
$ gdb hello-world.o
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.11.1
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from hello-world.o...Reading symbols from /Users/noah/c++/hello-world.o.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/hello-world.o...done.
done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /Users/noah/c++/hello-world.o
warning: `/private/tmp/gcc6-20160515-25034-1nu0tpk/gcc-6.1.0/build/x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/compatibility-atomic-c++0x.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/gcc6-20160515-25034-1nu0tpk/gcc-6.1.0/build/x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/compatibility-c++0x.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/gcc6-20160515-25034-1nu0tpk/gcc-6.1.0/build/x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/compatibility-chrono.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
(many more messages omitted)
warning: `/private/tmp/gcc6-20160515-25034-1nu0tpk/gcc-6.1.0/build/x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0/libgcc/unordtf2_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/gcc6-20160515-25034-1nu0tpk/gcc-6.1.0/build/x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0/libgcc/unwind-c_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
warning: `/private/tmp/gcc6-20160515-25034-1nu0tpk/gcc-6.1.0/build/x86_64-apple-darwin15.2.0/libgcc/unwind-dw2_s.o': can't open to read symbols: No such file or directory.
Hello World
[Inferior 1 (process 2319) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

I'm using OS X El Capitan, with G++ 6.1.0 and GDB 7.11.1, both installed through Homebrew. GDB is codesigned using [these instructions](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin).

Comment: I just started having the same problem after upgrading from gcc 6.1 to 6.2 using brew.